# How to customize the cookie generator of identityserver? (add claims into token but not into cookies)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, duende-identity-server

I am using the IdentityServer and I have a React client. so when I try to login into my client after checking credentials IDP generates some cookies in my browser. I read about these cookies (especially.AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie) and discovered that some user information is stored in these cookies such as claims and roles.
So I want to customize the cookie generator and remove some useless information from there. there are two questions:

1- how can I substitute the default cookie generator with a customized one?

2- are claims and roles needed for any other flows or I can remove the without any concerns?

Comment: Do you have a `ProfileService` implemented?  Usually `GetProfileDataAsync` is the place where claims are embedded in tokens etc. If you clear `ProfileDataRequestContext.IssuedClaims` then your cookie should not contain any claims.

Comment: No I had not reimplement it. and I think Idp is using the default one. but it was a great hint. I did not test it but are you sure clearing the `ProfileDataRequestContext.IssuedClaims` does not have any effect on my token? I need the claims on my token but not on my cookies

Comment: I checked it, it will remove claims from claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
We can customize the Authentication cookie using this [link](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/ui/login/session/).

If I want to summarize this article you should change the login action fellow:

1- If you are using `PasswordSignInAsync` you should change it to `CheckPasswordSignInAsync` because the first one is using the default cookie generation workflow but 2nd has no action for cookie creation.

2- for creating the cookie you should use  `HttpContext.SignInAsync` method. It will generate the authentication cookie for you. Remember that SubId is a required claim that must be included in the cookie. this is the cookie generator section of my code:

```
var claims = new List<Claim> { new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Subject, user.Id.ToString()) };
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
claims.Add(new Claim("user_type", $@"{user.UserType}"));
var claimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "pwd");
await HttpContext.SignInAsync("Identity.Application",new ClaimsPrincipal(claimIdentity),new AuthenticationProperties
                            {
                                IsPersistent = true
                            });
```